# Slide in div on scroll from left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load the `DIV` with slide-in effect from left and right, but this is when I scroll to the current screen and when scroll to the next div, the above element move out from left and right (reverse animation)

How this can be achieved? I tried with the Animate `CSS`, so it just slide in on page load but not on scroll, any help?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/dz9tap5b/1/) of what I have created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `.scrollTop()` with `jQuery?` This will start a animation when the user has scrolled a certain amount on your page, for example 300px `.scrollTop(300px)`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
   $('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft'); 
 } 
});
```

Comment: thanks, but wondering, how can I achieve this animate.css plugin?

Comment: $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300px) {
       $('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
    }
});

Comment: I hope it helps, I formatted the code properly in my original post